# Dictionary to XML C#

Tags: xml, linq, c#-4.0

I have a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and i want it to convert into XML, using Linq.

```
<Root>
<Key>TKey1</Key>
<Value>TValue1</Value>
<Key>TKey2</Key>
<Value>TValue2</Value>
<Key>TKey3</Key>
<Value>TValue3</Value>
</Root>
```

Right Now I am using  `var xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", values.Select(entry => new XElement(entry.Key, entry.Value))));`

And i am getting

```
<Root>
<TKey1>TValue1</TKey1>
<TKey2>TValue2</TKey2>
<TKey3>TValue3</TKey3>
</Root>
```

Comment: You need Visual Studio or at least notepad and C# compiler

Comment: That's a poor structure as there would be be no way to relate key and values nodes without considering their ordinality

Comment: I have edited my question please have a look.

Comment: The format you want is not very good and could cause problems, whats wrong with the `<TKey1>TValue1</TKey1>` format? Personally I much prefer `<key name="TKey1">TValue1</key>`

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! But it a requirement, so I asked.

Comment: The code required to navigate your desired XML is going to be super hacky, because the structure is so poorly thought out...! The key and the value need to be bound within a common node or  a parent node for the structure to really work. In actuality the generated output is much safer to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Alex already mentioned, structure of your desired xml is not good, but if you need it for some legacy system..

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("Root",
            dictionary.SelectMany(kvp => new []
            {
                new XElement("Key", kvp.Key),
                new XElement("Value", kvp.Value)
            })));
```

For sample dictionary

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string> { [1] = "Bob", [2] = "Mike" };
```

Result is

```
<Root>
  <Key>1</Key>
  <Value>Bob</Value>
  <Key>2</Key>
  <Value>Mike</Value>
</Root>
```

---

NOTE: Consider to use some better xml structure, which is much easier to read and parse, something that corresponds to structure of dictionary. E.g.

```
<Root>
  <Item key="1">Bob</Item>
  <Item key="2">Mike</Item>
</Root>
```

Now it's easy to read and manipulate:

```
var item = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//Item[@key=2]"); // "Mike"
```